# Congruence in the solutions of an expression $ax\equiv b \pmod{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I need to proof the following statement:

Let $a, b, n \in \Bbb{Z}$  with $ n≥ 2, gcd(a,n)=1$. Proof that if $s_{1},s_{2}$ are solutions to $ax\equiv b \pmod{n}$, then $s_{1}\equiv s_{2} \pmod{n}$.

I don't know where to start my proof. I do know that if you get any solution, then by adding the modulo you get equivalent solutions. Then, there are n possible solutions. But I don't think my argument is correct.

Comment: Since $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then you can invert $a$ mod $n$. So $s_1 \equiv a^{-1} b \equiv s_2 \pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $s_1,s_2$ are solutions, $as_1\equiv as_2\equiv b\pmod n$, so $as_1\equiv as_2\pmod n$.

Hence, $n\mid a(s_2-s_1)$. But, since $\gcd(a,n)=1$,

$$n\mid s_2-s_1$$ so $s_1\equiv s_2\pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in\Bbb Z$ is such ${\rm gcd}(a,n)=1$ then $a$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$, i.e. there exists $a^*\in\Bbb Z$ such that $aa^*\equiv1\bmod n$.

Thus, if you have a congruence
$$
ab_1\equiv ab_2\bmod n
$$
simply multiplying both hands by the multiplicative inverse $a^*$ gives
$$
b_1\equiv b_2\bmod n.
$$
This is false if ${\rm gcd}(a,n)\neq1$, e.g. $2\cdot1\equiv2\cdot4\bmod6$ but $1\not\equiv4\bmod6$.

Comment: Or more simple, $a\in(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$.